# What happens when QTcpSocket::close() is called?

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, tcp

What happens when `QTcpSocket::close()` is called?

I know it ultimately closes the connection, but what happens to the Tcp socket's internal buffer? Is it cleared?

Is this why `QTcpSocket::size()` returns 0 when I call `close()`?

From the client after receiving data from server:

```
qDebug() << tcpSocket.size(); //170
tcpSocket.close();
qDebug () << tcpSocket.size(); //0
```

Edit:
According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914286/what-does-it-mean-to-flush-a-socket), closing a socket automatically flushes any remaining data. Since I close the socket after the client has received data from the server, where does the data get flushed to? I haven't read any of the data yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When close is called, Qt changes the `QAbstractSocket` state to `ClosingState`.

If there is data that has not been written to the socket, it is written now. Once that finishes, the socket is completely closed (I'm considering only the Qt "view" of the socket, not its implementation and the control states like TIME_WAIT).

Looking at the source of `QAbstractSocket` class [here](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/cf79da9933513454501be55210937cba36b5a29d:src/network/socket/qabstractsocket.cpp#L1236), and following to the `QNativeSocketEngine` class, looks like Qt do not store a read buffer for the socket, completely relying on the operating system for that.

So, once the socket is closed, the read buffer no longer exists and all non-read data is lost.

Conclusion: before closing the socket, be sure to read its data until `bytesAvaiable` reaches `0` (or some imposed restriction).

Comment: So the internal buffer that `QAbstractSocket`'s docs are referring to are actually created by the operating system?

Comment: Yes. I haven't found anything pointing to Qt managing buffers.

Comment: Okay thank you. In the docs, it was worded such that I thought `QAbstractSocket` creates a buffer.

Comment: `QTcpSocket` definitely *does* allocate internal buffers. I can't find any documentation to that effect. Moreover, calling `QTcpSocket::disconnectFromHost()` does *not* issue the `close(2)` call, presumably because it's still trying to write from it's internal buffer.

Comment: The docs does not state anything about buffers, indeed. But, as I stated,  while inspecting the code I could not find anything related. Maybe in a different version of the code, or maybe I was not cautious enough. Right now, gitorious is under maintenance, so I'm not able to double check it.