# Java Client and Server connected but not communicating

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

so I'm trying to create a Client - Server chat application and I've got the program already written. The client and server connect through a common port(5000) on localhost. The server and client connect (the console confirms this with a system.out) however when I prompt the server to send a println out to the client to prompt the user to enter a username nothing happens. Please help.

Client:

```
//ChatClient.java

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import java.io.*;

import java.net.Socket;

public class ChatClient {

    static JFrame chatWindow = new JFrame("OneOh");

    static JTextArea chatArea = new JTextArea(20, 50);

    static JTextField textField = new JTextField(40);

    static JLabel blankLabel = new JLabel("           ");

    static JButton sendButton = new JButton("Send");

    static BufferedReader in;

    static PrintWriter out;

    static JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("         ");

    private Socket soc;



    ChatClient()

    {



        chatWindow.setLayout(new FlowLayout());



        chatWindow.add(nameLabel);

        chatWindow.add(new JScrollPane(chatArea));

        chatWindow.add(blankLabel);

        chatWindow.add(textField);

        chatWindow.add(sendButton);

        chatWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        chatWindow.setSize(475, 500);

        chatWindow.setVisible(true);



        textField.setEditable(false);

        chatArea.setEditable(false);



        sendButton.addActionListener(new Listener());

        textField.addActionListener(new Listener());

    }





    void startChat() throws Exception

    {

       String ipAddress = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(

                chatWindow,

                "Enter IP Address:",

                "IP Address Required",

                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);    



       soc = new Socket(ipAddress, 5000);

       in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(soc.getInputStream()));

       out = new PrintWriter(soc.getOutputStream(), true);

       while (true)

       {

         String str = in.readLine();

           if (str.equals("NAMEREQUIRED"))

           {

           String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(

                       chatWindow,

                       "Enter a unique name:",

                       "Name Required!!",

                       JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);



               out.println(name);



           }

           else if(str.equals("NAMEALREADYEXISTS"))

           {

           String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(

                       chatWindow,

                       "Enter another name:",

                       "Name Already Exits!!",

                       JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);



               out.println(name);

           }

           else if (str.startsWith("NAMEACCEPTED"))

           {

               textField.setEditable(true);

               nameLabel.setText("You are logged in as: "+str.substring(12));



           }

           else

           {

               chatArea.append(str + "\n");

           }

       }

   }



      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ChatClient client = new ChatClient();

            client.startChat();

      }

}

class Listener implements ActionListener

{

      @Override

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ChatClient.out.println(ChatClient.textField.getText());

            ChatClient.textField.setText("");

      }



}
```

server:

```
//ChatServer.java

import java.io.*;

import java.net.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ChatServer {



      static ArrayList<String> userNames = new ArrayList<String>();

      static ArrayList<PrintWriter> printWriters = new ArrayList<PrintWriter>();

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

           System.out.println("Waiting for clients..."); 

          @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(5000);

           while (true)

           {

             Socket soc = ss.accept();

               System.out.println("Connection established");

             ConversationHandler handler = new ConversationHandler(soc);

             handler.start();

           }



      }

}

class ConversationHandler extends Thread

{

    Socket socket;

    BufferedReader in;

    PrintWriter out;

    String name;

    PrintWriter pw;

    static FileWriter fw;

    static BufferedWriter bw;



   public ConversationHandler(Socket socket) throws IOException {

        this.socket = socket;

        fw = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Edoardo Sella\\Desktop\\ChatServer-Logs.txt",true);

        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        pw = new PrintWriter(bw);

    }

   public void run()

   {

        try

        {

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

            while (true)

            {

               int _count = 0;

               if(_count > 0)

               {
                    out.println("NAMEALREADYEXISTS");

               }

               else

               {

                    out.println("NAMEREQUIRED");

               }



               name = in.readLine();



               if (name == null)

               {

                   return;

               }



               if (!ChatServer.userNames.contains(name))

               {

                  ChatServer.userNames.add(name);

                  break;

               }

             _count++;

           }



            out.println("NAMEACCEPTED"+name);

            ChatServer.printWriters.add(out);



            while (true)

            {

                String message = in.readLine();



                if (message == null)

                {

                    return;

                }



                pw.println(name + ": " + message);

                for (PrintWriter writer : ChatServer.printWriters) {

                    writer.println(name + ": " + message);

                }

            }



        }

        catch (Exception e)

        {

            System.out.println(e);

        }

   }

}
```

I'm really confused as to why the Client doesn't receive the out.println command any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: Wall of code. Please get rid of all the Swing code and as many of the blank lines as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple errors here.

The most important one is about the logic: on the server side, you first listen to an incoming message from the client:

```
name = in.readLine();
```

which is blocking. In the client side, you do exactly the same:

```
String str = in.readLine();
```

So, **both sides are waiting for an incoming message**, which will never come. Simply add something like:

```
out.println("hello")
```

at the beginning of the `run` method of `ConversationHandler` and you will see your message is actually correctly received by the client.

You absolutely need to alternate here, i.e. choose one to send a message first.

Also, **don't forget to flush** the output stream, or even better use:

```
out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
```

Notice the `true`: it will make the printwriter *autoflush*, i.e. always send messages right away (vs keeping them in cache), even if the message is small. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914286/what-does-it-mean-to-flush-a-socket) for more info about flushing.

---

Some additional remarks:

- use blank lines wisely: addind a blank line between every statement makes the code very large and difficult to read. Instead, use a blank lines to separate logical blocks
- in the conversation handler (run method), you have the line:

  ```
  int _count = 0;
  if (_count > 0)
  ```

  it is easy to see that the condition will always be true
- try not to hardcode file paths (`new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Edoardo Sella\\Desktop\\ChatServer-Logs.txt", true);`. Prefer relative file paths or at least put them inside a global final variable easy to find and change

Comment: Thank you so much. The problem was the printwriter was just keeping the messages in cache rather than sending them. Much appreciated